# How can i solve the incomplete type error in c++?

Tags: c++

i am working with INET framework 3.2.2 for omnetpp v4.6. My code is importing .h files from the INET framework but this error of incomplete type keeps coming up even though I've added the INET framework in my codes references and i have written the complete path directory in the #include and i forward declared the classes i need but it still doesn't recognize the attributes i am using and gives me "incomplete type" error yet they're recognized perfectly fine in the inline bool operator with no errors. 
Here is the code:

```
#ifndef OPENFLOW_H_
#define OPENFLOW_H_

#define OFP_VERSION   0x01

#include "inet/common/INETDefs.h"

//doesn't recognize the includes
#include <inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4Address.h>
#include <inet/linklayer/common/MACAddress.h> 

class MACAddress; 
class IPv4Address;


struct oxm_basic_match {
    int OFB_IN_PORT;
    MACAddress OFB_ETH_DST; //error (field 'OFB_ETH_DST' has incomplete type 'MACAddress')
    MACAddress OFB_ETH_SRC; //error (field 'OFB_ETH_SRC' has incomplete type 'MACAddress')
    int OFB_ETH_TYPE;
    IPv4Address OFB_IPV4_DST; //error (field 'OFB_IPV4_DST' has incomplete type 'IPv4Address')
    int OFB_ARP_OP; /* ARP opcode. */ 
    IPv4Address OFB_ARP_SPA; /* ARP source IPv4 address. */ //error (field 'OFB_ARP_SPA' has incomplete type 'IPv4Address')
    IPv4Address OFB_ARP_TPA; /* ARP target IPv4 address. */ //error (field 'OFB_ARP_TPA' has incomplete type 'IPv4Address')
    MACAddress OFB_ARP_SHA; /* ARP source hardware address. */ //error (field 'OFB_ARP_SHA' has incomplete type 'MACAddress')
    MACAddress OFB_ARP_THA; /* ARP target hardware address. */ //error (field 'OFB_ARP_THA' has incomplete type 'MACAddress')
    uint32_t wildcards;
    int getPriority();
};


inline bool operator==(const oxm_basic_match &m1, const oxm_basic_match& m2) {
    return m2.OFB_IN_PORT == m1.OFB_IN_PORT
            && m2.OFB_ETH_DST == m1.OFB_ETH_DST
            && m2.OFB_ETH_SRC == m1.OFB_ETH_SRC
            && m2.OFB_ETH_TYPE == m1.OFB_ETH_TYPE
            && m2.OFB_ARP_OP == m1.OFB_ARP_OP
            && m2.OFB_ARP_SHA == m1.OFB_ARP_SHA
            && m2.OFB_ARP_SPA == m1.OFB_ARP_SPA
            && m2.OFB_ARP_THA == m1.OFB_ARP_THA
            && m2.OFB_ARP_TPA == m1.OFB_ARP_TPA;
}
```

any help please ?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use forward declaration in this case. You should include the header file containing the full class definition. class MACAddress {...}

Forward declaration can be used only for pointers or references. Here is a more complete answer - [When can I use a forward declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-can-i-use-a-forward-declaration)

Comment: Can you please tell me more about how to do that ?? Do you mean i should add the attributes of the .h file i am importing, the MACAddress and IPv4Address ??

Comment: I don't know the libraries you are using... But you should do something  like
#include <xxx>
where xxx is name of a header file where a classes MACAddress and IPv4Address are defined.

Look if these are in inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4Address.h and inet/linklayer/common/MACAddress.h

Comment: classes MACAddress and IPv4Address are the .h files that are in inet/networklayer/contract/ipv4/IPv4Address.h and inet/linklayer/common/MACAddress.h.. I included them both from the inet framework and it still gives me the incomplete type error, and when i remove the forward declaration it gives me "MACAddress does not name a type" and "IPv4Address does not name a type"

Comment: Looks like you should use namespace resolution: inet::MACAddress or using namespace inet;

Comment: The namespace resolution doesn't work.. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Doesn't work means what? What does the compiler say? Have you removed the forward declarations?

Comment: It worked!! I removed the forward declarations and added using namespace inet and it worked. Thank you alot.